# <script> tag containing JSON in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to render this snippet inside a react component

```
<div id="root:iex-widget"></div>
<script id="iex-widget-script-tag" type="text/javascript" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/iexcloud-hl37opg/static/single-ticker.bundle.js">
{
"autoWidth": "false",
"colorTheme": "dark",
"stockSymbol": "uber",
"width": "400",
"apiToken": `${API_KEY}`
}
</script>
```

^^the snippet above will be rendered inside a `<li>` tag, so it will be rendered multiple times inside the document body. I cannot create the script tag inside `componentDidMount()` since the component will get re-rendered with different JSON parameters. I did not have any success with the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute. Is there any way I could render this?

Comment: What are you trying to render? What specifically is your expected result? The literal "JSON" text with an evaluated API_KEY?

Comment: the expected result is a styled widget which the script tag will place inside the div given the JSON data @DrewReese

Comment: It may be helpful to include your react code as it is still unclear what you're trying to accomplish, what you've tried, and what may or may not be working.